# Can't connect to Oracle instance

Tags: oracle, ssh, cloud, vps, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I can't connect to my oracle instance. It worked yesterday, but oracle has updated kernel, I got message form Ubuntu in ssh console`** System reboot required **`, so I typed reboot and from then it's not working. Tried to reboot it, stop and start, Send diagnostic interrupt and Send diagnostic reboot from their dashboard but none option is working.

What should I do?

Console history logs from oracle: https://pastebin.com/raw/8y6Nmtfj

Comment: Please paste error messages as text, not images. Was your server running *on* Ubuntu, or is that just where your app / client is located and the database is somewhere else? Oracle would not push patches to your operating system, in particular since Ubuntu is not an Oracle product.

Comment: You have a kernel panic - that is an OS / driver issue, not a database issue. Please update your tags.

Comment: It's not database, but Oracle cloud compute instance. Please help me someone. It's similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562413/how-to-restore-fix-vm-standard-e2-1-micro-always-free-instances-that-went-into